# Counter using Ultrasonic Sensor (self.arduino)

Tags: sensors

I am doing a pretty simple arduino project that uses a Parallax Ping Ultrasonic Sensor to increment a counter when an object moves past the desired distance. (object leaves, counter goes up, object comes back, this loops forever). My problem is now that every time i run this.. the serial monitor just shows me Count: 1 over and over again and does not increment.
Any help would be appreciated!

example of what i want the Serial Monitor to write:
Count:0 
Count:1 
Count:2 ....

What it is currently doing:
Count:0 
Count:0 
Count:0

```
const int pingPin = 7;

void setup() {
  // initialize serial communication:
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{
  // establish variables for duration of the ping,
  // and the distance result in inches and centimeters:
  long duration, inches, cm, count;

  // The PING))) is triggered by a HIGH pulse of 2 or more microseconds.
  // Give a short LOW pulse beforehand to ensure a clean HIGH pulse:
  pinMode(pingPin, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(pingPin, LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(2);
  digitalWrite(pingPin, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(5);
  digitalWrite(pingPin, LOW);

  // The same pin is used to read the signal from the PING))): a HIGH
  // pulse whose duration is the time (in microseconds) from the sending
  // of the ping to the reception of its echo off of an object.
  pinMode(pingPin, INPUT);
  duration = pulseIn(pingPin, HIGH);

    // convert the time into a distance
  inches = microsecondsToInches(duration);
  cm = microsecondsToCentimeters(duration);
// count = 1;

 if (inches > 5)
{
  Serial.print("Count: ");
  Serial.print(count);
  Serial.print('\n');
  delay(1000);
        count++;

}

}


long microsecondsToInches(long microseconds)
{
  return microseconds / 74 / 2;
}

long microsecondsToCentimeters(long microseconds)
{

  return microseconds / 29 / 2;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Count is a local variable - it gets re-created afresh every time the loop() runs.

Either make it global, or make it static.

These two options look like this:

**Global**

```
long count = 0;

void loop()
{
  // establish variables for duration of the ping,
  // and the distance result in inches and centimeters:
  long duration, inches, cm;
```

**Static**

```
void loop()
{
  // establish variables for duration of the ping,
  // and the distance result in inches and centimeters:
  long duration, inches, cm;
  static long count = 0;
```

Both will do the same job, but the `static` form is preferred since it is always better to keep a variable's scope as narrow as possible.  It is also important to provide a start value for the counter to begin from (0 in this case) otherwise the starting value will be unknown.

Comment: i did int count inside the loop and it still didn't do anything...

Comment: You need to place it outside the `loop` (i.e. global).